# Why does every single Doubleclick ad load the same amp4ads JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, performance, double-click-advertising

We have 3 or 4 Google / Doubleclick ads on our website per page. Every single one of the ads on a single page is loading 'amp4ads-v0.js' (54 KB) and 'amp-analytics-01.js' (40 KB). This is adding significant load time for our users, especially mobile, and has caused testing such as Lighthouse to make a real point of how taxing these files are. There's effectively 300 KB of data loaded for just 3 ads on one single page - this is outrageous and it didn't used to be this way.

Is there a way to disallow 'amp4ads' js files, or only have them load once per page, or otherwise edit our ad settings or coding methods to address this? I cannot find documentation or answers about it.

aside: This is on top of the eternally annoying 'SameSite' alerts in the Chrome console logs: I am frustrated why Google products aren't up to the company's own standards of speed and cannot pass even the tests provided by them.

Comment: please expand on the `SameSite` error you are getting from google ads, each ad space on your site is treated differently so different advertisers can target it specifically - i would contact doubleclick account manager and ask him for solutions as im sure you are far from the only person this is affecting?

Comment: @Dan I get the feeling I do need to push this up the chain and have someone contact doubleclick directly about the performance problems. The second issue (and me just piling on complaints) typically looks like:

A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: This def looks like an misconfiguration on the publisher side of your double click account. I would have an AM from DC look over your site and provide suggestions - they make money on making sure you as a publisher is serving properly